# LibreOffice doesn't install anything except Writer and Draw?

Tags: installation, libreoffice

So I tried to install LibreOffice, because the free version of Microsoft Office I got for being a student has been giving my laptop a BSOD (separate problem, working on it). There was an older installation there, but it only had Writer and Draw.

So, I downloaded the latest version and ran the installer.

As you may know, there's no option to not install specific parts of the suite anymore -- it all gets installed. I did a custom install, and when I got to the screen that tried to set LibreOffice as the default opener for the Microsoft Office filetypes, Excel and Powerpoint files were greyed out.

I assumed this meant it wouldn't install the other components (I was right).

[image: Greyed Out]

So, I went back and did a basic install, which I assumed would install everything.

It didn't.

Once I realized it hadn't, I went and reinstalled it through the command line using Chocolatey.

No dice.

I haven't been able to find anything online about this. In the meantime, I've installed OpenOffice, because I have some stuff that I need to do for class.

I really do prefer LibreOffice though, and am very confused about why only half of it is installing!

Thanks,

evamvid

TL;DR: Old LibreOffice install only had Writer and Draw, new install did that too, even with multiple reinstalls.

Comment: Just a guess, but the old installation preferences may be driving the new installation.  Totally uninstall all versions of LibreOffice, then reinstall.

Comment: Yep, I had the same hunch, did it, and it worked! I had just come to post an answer/close the question. Great minds think alike, I guess!

Comment: BTW, great avatar.  Too bad it's too small to see on a post.

Comment: You should add that as a proper answer below.